# Typescript namespace can't be found when using Gulp+Browserify

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I have been working with namespaces in a project, which is going fine, until all of a sudden this 'Test' namespace just can't be found. Am I missing something?

```
Can't find variable: Test in Game.ts
```

**example.ts**

```
namespace Test { 
    export class Example {        
        constructor() {           
            console.log("example");
        }
    } 
}
```

**game.ts**

```
/// <reference path="test/example.ts"/>
namespace Game {
    export class Snippet {    
        constructor() {
            // Test is not found
            let s = new Test.Example();
        }
    } 
}

// Game.Snippet IS found
window.addEventListener("load", () => new Game.Snippet());
```

**UPDATE**

Upon closer inspection I think it's a bug in my gulpfile or with browserify. When I compile with the default tsc action it works! But when using browserify it fails. I followed [this tutorial](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html)

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require("tsify");
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task("build", function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['dev/main.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("docs/js"));
});
```

Comment: Add `tsconfig.json` or all flags passed to `tsc` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that your folder structure as following:

[image: folder structure]

Based on that you may try t set the reference as following

```
/// <reference path="./test/example.ts"/>
```

**Update**

I had tried to export the namespaces and imported them. It worked fine inside an ionic sample project

**example.ts**

```
export namespace Test { 
    export class Example {        
        constructor() {           
            console.log("example");
        }
    } 
}
```

**game.ts**

```
import {Test} from "./test/example"/>
export namespace Game {
    export class Snippet {    
        constructor() {
            // Test is not found
            let s = new Test.Example();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: sorry no, that makes no difference. I've even put the file in the same directory.

Comment: You may need to compile them all into one file using `--outfile` flag to `tsc` https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces.md

Comment: @AmrElAdawy outFile is completely unrelated

Comment: I had tried it to compile ts into one js and it worked.

Comment: Upon closer inspection I think it's a bug in my gulpfile or with browserify. When I compile with the default tsc action it works! But when using browserify it fails. I followed this tutorial : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html